# Allow DHCP to Update Bind9 DNS with Samba AD

Tags: networking, 20.04, samba, dns, dhcp

So I'm upgrading our current NT4 domain to Samba AD with Bind9 DNS. Our current DHCP/DNS setup is on one server, separate from the Domain server. With Samba AD, we'll be using Samba's tools to manage the DNS, thus allowing use of things like the Windows Server Admin Tool suite (DNS, AD Users & Groups, etc.). So Bind9, isc-dhcp-server, and Samba is all going to be on the same machine for the new setup.

Following [Samba's guide](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_DHCP_to_update_DNS_records_with_BIND9) on how to set this up, I noticed some glaring issues in `/var/log/syslog` once we started passing some traffic to this server. Most notably being various uncaught exceptions from leases expiring. Looking deeper, this is caused from the script not having all of the required args that `samba-tool` requires to delete an entry in DNS, specifically the Record name (e.g if the record was my-pc.domain.com, it isn't passing the my-pc piece). There's a comment stating that there is a reason they can't get this, which leaves me wondering: Is there just a better way in general to handle this?

So that's what I'm looking for here: How can I efficiently handle Dynamic DNS updates from DHCP through Samba so records are updated on the fly and updated/deleted when appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. If it isn't then there may be something wrong with your setup.

Did you by any chance miss the blue box at the bottom of the wikipage that says this:

Do not log a bug report on Samba bugzilla for any problems you have with this set up, ask on the samba mailing list.

So, come and ask me about my script on the samba mailing list.

Comment: Posted to the mailing list!

Comment: For those that may have a similar issue, you can follow the discussion on the Samba Mailing List archive: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2021-January/234130.html